# redux-form multiple checkbox, values in a single array without bool values

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I know that checkbox receive a bool value, so what can i do to change this with multiple checkbox.

below is where i have my all checkbox, the JSX file, each checkbox is a category and user can choose one or more categories

```
<div className='columns is-multiline'>
  {this.props.propsCategories.data.list.map((category, i) => (
    <div key={ i } className='column is-one-quarter'>
      <Field
        name='category[]'
        label={ category.title }
        component={ WrapperInputCheckbox }
        setCategory={(e) => this.handleChange(e, category.id)}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

in my handleChange i'm just trying change a single value.

```
//handleChange
handleChange = (e, id) => {
  e.target.value = id
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

but when i submit my form in category array i get

```
Category: Array[0]
  "" : true
  length : 0
```

the value still a bool :X

i need the value become a array like

```
category['id-1', 'id-n']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a compound name in the **id** using the *name* of the input or passing a prop with other word.

Also you should use *map*, is useful when you want to apply the function to every item, also it's simpler and more concise than using a *for loop* to build a list.

```
<div className={classNameContentGroup}>
    { items.map((item) => (
        <div className={`${classNameContent } `"}>
            <input
                {...input}
                name={name}
                type="checkbox"
                value={ item.value }
                className={className}
                id={ `${name}-${item.value}` }
            />
            <label className={classNameLabel} htmlFor={ `${ nameR}-${item.value}` }>
                {item.label}
            </label>
        </div>
    ))
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution!

Comment: Done! @Benjamin